# I am having trouble getting my h3 tags and p tags in my section tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am reading data from a javascript file and then importing them into the HTML file. The issue I am having is that I am unable to get my p tags and h3 tags in my section tag. This is what it looks like when I load it up:

[image: click here]

The following code is what I have tried. I have used inner HTML to create the tags and I am not sure what I can do to fix this.

```js
// create a box class section for whole thing
containerElement.innerHTML += "<section class='flight-info'> ";

// another class for top part of box 
containerElement.innerHTML += "<div class='topBox' ";
// add all the elements such as destination and code
containerElement.innerHTML += "<h3 class='destination'> " + FlightInfo[i].destination + " </h3>";
containerElement.innerHTML += "<p class='departTime'> Depart time: " + FlightInfo[i].departTime + " </p>";


// have to check for # of stops to format. if its not 0, we can add the # of stops and time, otherwise its Non-stop, time
if (FlightInfo[i].stops != 0) {
  containerElement.innerHTML += "<p class='timeStop'>" + FlightInfo[i].stops + ", " + FlightInfo[i].time + " min </p>";
} else if (FlightInfo[i].stops == 0) {
  containerElement.innerHTML += "<p class='timeStop'> Non-Stop" + ", " + FlightInfo[i].time + " min </p>";
}

// end the topBox class
containerElement.innerHTML += "</div>"

containerElement.innerHTML += "</section>"
```

Comment: **containerElement.innerHTML += "<div class='topBox' ";** is missing the end **>**

Comment: I did that, it's just the same thing but added a div tag. I'm trying to get the h3 and p tags inside the section and div respectively.

Comment: You have a coding error, it should be: containerElement.innerHTML += "<div class='topBox'>";

Comment: I fixed that, its the same problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you keep adding everything to the container.

```
containerElement.innerHTML +=
```

You only need the code above one time (at least the way you're doing it now), and add *everything* in one long string.

Otherwise, add the section, then select the section and add everything to the section's innerHTML. Same idea with the div.